# How to import DLL to c# testing project

Tags: c#, nunit

Im working through the below tutorial on NUnit at the moment, but Im stuck about halfway through because I dont know what the author is referring to when he says 'Import the downloaded DLL files into the project'. Can anyone take a look and tell me what these dll files are? I have done all the coding up to this point, I'm just not sure what these are/ how to import them to my project. Thanks.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178635/Unit-Testing-Using-NUnit

Comment: Have you downloaded the NUnit framework as described in the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects are available for download. You'll see the author created NUnit_Application (a console app) and NUnit_Application.Test (a class library). You will also see a folder called "NUnit Rferences" under NUnit_Application. When he says import the downloaded dll, he means put it anywhere on your hard drive (in this case he put it under the NUnit_Application folder) and add a reference to it (nunit.framework.dll) via the "Add References". In this case, the NUnit_Application.Test would be referencing that dll, as its the one using the classes within that dll.

Note that the author is downloading and referencing the dll's manually. You can achieve the same via NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Package Manager Console and issue this command:

```
Install-Package NUnit.Runners
```

That's probably what the author meant, but NuGet is the way to go these days.

Note that if you have Resharper, Continuous Tests, NCrunch etc, you don't need the old-fashioned NUnit runner and can use the ones built into those tools. In which case you need `NUnit` rather than `NUnit.Runners`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to `nunit.framework.dll`, which you have probably downloaded earlier. Better yet, use nuget to install it: `Install-Package NUnit`